# OpenSSL SSL_CTX_new crash when run as win32 service

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, ssl, openssl

I am facing a weird problem of OpenSSL: it seems that SSL_CTX_new() function crashes when my application is run as a win32 service (either Local Service / Network Service or System Service).

My code looks like this:

```
int main() {
   SSL_library_init();

   const int nLocks = CRYPTO_num_locks();

   ossl_mtx_pool = new mutexT* [nLocks]; // simple wrapper class over mutexes
   for(int i = 0; i < nLocks; ++i)
      ossl_mtx_pool[i] = new mutexT;

   CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback(ossl_threadid_function); // returns win32 thread id
   CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(ossl_locking_fun); // simple function that calls mutexT::lock/unlock)

   OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
   SSL_load_error_strings();
   ERR_load_BIO_strings();

   // some other app initialization here...

   // run win32 service thread OR just a seaparate thread
}

// called later on in the context of a different thread
int myclient()
{
   myCtx *ctx = new connContextT;
   const SSL_METHOD *mm = SSLv23_client_method();
   if(mm == 0) {
      // print some error whcih doesn't show up
   }   

   printf("I'm Here!\n"); //< this print shows up       

   ctx->sslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(mm);
   // crash >HERE< before being able to print anything else

   // some code to connect to server
}
```

The really weird thing is that if I run this application as a normal win32 app (i.e. not calling win32 service functions but still running myclient() in a separate thread) everything works flawless.

I'm compiling with mingw32 gcc 4.7.1 on win7 and I'm linking openssl statically (no DLLs).

Any help in trying to understand the problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: After some debugging it seems that the crash occurs within RAND_pseudo_bytes function

Comment: I know nothing about the OpenSSL source, but I suspect the failure is occurring before RAND_pseudo_bytes, but it's crashing (likely with a null dereference) there.  If you could post a stack backtrace, that might help.

Comment: I use OpenSSL in Win32 services and it works fine for me, so this has to be a problem with your particular build of OpenSSL. Where did you get it? Did you compile it yourself, or are you using a third-party pre-compiled build?  I use the Win32 build that is linked to in the [Binaries](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) section of OpenSSL's website.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
@Eric: I'm actually pretty sure the crash is within that function as the trace is just one level deep (SSL_CTX_new --> RAND_pseudo_bytes).

Comment: @Remy: I'm building openssl 1.0.1e from source with mingw. Congigure options are "no-idea no-camellia no-seed no-bf no-cast no-rc2 no-rc4 no-rc5 no-md2 no-md4 no-ripemd no-mdc2 no-ec no-ecdsa no-ecdh no-shared no-asm"

Answer (score 0):

after more debugging I've found a very stupid bug in the ossl_threadid_function (!!!)
apparently returning the wrong ID causes stack corruption within openssl, this is why I failed to produce any useful backtrace.

Surprisingly enough, running the app as a normal process rather than a service didn't caused any problem, not even run-time tools as Application Verifier noted that. Obviously this has something to do with the fact that services instance at least one more thread...

Sorry about this and thank you all for your time.
Regards.